# How to align vertically a `inline-block` element inside a `<td>` element?

Tags: css, html

I can't manage to align vertically a `inline-block` `<span>` element inside a `<td>` element (which has its default `display: table-cell` style).

Both elements have fixed sizes: the `<td> is 24px tall and so is the``.

I would expect both elements to have the same rendered size, as none of them has a margin or a padding. However, it seems the `<td>` is somehow taller than expected and I can't figure out why.

Example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxmhC/).

Do you know why that happens and how to "fix" it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `font-size:0` to td class

```
td {
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; font-size:0
}
```

Updated Demo http://jsfiddle.net/NxmhC/1/

Comment: Thanks, seems to work perfectly ! Do you have any detailed explanation of why that happens ?

Answer (score 2):

Align the span:

```
span.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: lime;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```